# Can you tell symmetry and orthogonality given some 2x2 matrix with its trace and determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, symmetry

I have an undefined 2x2 matrix with trace = 2 and determinant = 12. I need to figure out if it's diagonalizable, and if it can be symmetric, and orthogonal.

I've determined that its eigenvalues are 2 & 6 using:

$\lambda_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}(8\pm\sqrt{8^2-4(12)})=2,6$

And that therefor it is diagonizable since each eigenvalue's multiplicity is 1. However, I am unsure of how to find if it can be symmetric and orthogonal. I can't seem to find properties that would allow me to discern this. Is there a way to approach this given the information I have?

Comment: Hello :) Sure, it can be symmetric. Just take a diagonal matrix. Let $A$ be an orthogonal matrix, what do you know about $\langle Ax,Ax\rangle$? What do you know about $\langle Ax,Ax\rangle$, if $x$ is an eigenvector?

Comment: 2, 6 are not eigenvalues. To decide whether the matrix can be orthogonal, it suffices to read the definition of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Your eigenvalues are incorrect. You should find that the eigenvalues are
$$
\lambda_{\pm} = \frac 12 \left(2 \pm \sqrt{2^2 - 4(12)} \right) = 1 \pm i\sqrt{11}.
$$